# C++ и вставки ассемблера

Tags: ассемблер, c++

Я недавно выучил С++ на базовом уровне (стандартная библиотека+STL).
Решил немного подучить ассемблер (когда-то учил его, до конца так и не осилил).
Собственно вопрос, какие преимущества дают асм-вставки в С++ код, и как это оформить.

P.S. Всех с новым годом!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Преимущества:

1. Возможность оптимизации вручную
2. Использование (опять же для оптимизации) команд процессора, недоступных через стандартные средства С++
3. В случае программирование ядер - низкоуровневый доступ к оборудованию через порты ввода-вывода, к процессорным прерываниям для создания слоя абстракции.
4. и др. подобное

Как оформлять - зависит от компилятора и платформы.

С Новым годом!

Comment: Насчёт оформления было красиво в watcom'е. Вставки оформлялись как inline-процедуры.

Comment: 
в детстве я так и делал, когда у меня был спектрумзх :)



Answer (score 2):

Хотя здесь спрашивали про преимущества, я считаю, что надо рассказать и про недостатки:

1. inline-ассемблера нет в стандарте. Разные компиляторы могут по-разному его поддерживать.
2. Некроссплатформенность. Для каждой архитектуры процессора придётся писать свой код. Причём, большинство компиляторов поддерживают только ассемблер x86 кода. Программы, компилируемые под x64 или ARM не могут использовать inline ассемблер.
3. Насчёт оптимизации: помните правило `80\20`. В среднем 20% кода выполняется 80% времени. Надо оптимизировать только эту часть кода.
4. Очень часто у кода есть потенциал оптимизации и без использования ассемблера. Часто код можно ускорить в несколько раз, просто изменив алгоритм.
5. Если переписать код на ассемблер, не меняя алгоритм, то его можно ускорить очень незначительно. И то, надо очень постараться, потому что компилятор не такой тупой. Чтобы написать код быстрее сгенерированного компилятором нужно быть профессионалом, если, конечно, не использовать расширенные инструкции процессора, которые этот компилятор не поддерживает.

Вместо ассемблера лучше использовать хорошо оптимизирующий компилятор, например, intel C++. Также стоит стараться использовать intrinsic-функции, которые уже написаны на ассемблере и оптимизированы, и поставляются с компилятором. В Visual C++ примерами таких функций являются memcpy, memcmp, memmove.

Comment: Да это все ясно и правильно. В подавляющем большинстве случаев в обычных приложениях нет нужды использовать встроенный ассемблер. Главное его применение - в ядерном программировании, где без него никуда. Да и там его стараются применять по минимуму для облегчения переносимости кода. Я лично один раз получил реальную выгоду от применения ассемблера в случае использования инструкции bswap на х64 для оптимизации перевода чисел из big  endean в  little endean. 

Но ознакомиться с этой технологией, как и вообще знать ассемблер, полезно.

Comment: >Я лично один раз получил реальную выгоду от применения ассемблера в случае использования инструкции bswap на х64 для оптимизации перевода чисел из big endean в little endean.

 А зачем? Разве это может быть слабым местом программы? Насколько я понял, это был не встраиваемый ассемблер, так как x64 inline-ассемблера в компиляторах нет? Конечно, если это вынести в отдельную inline-функцию с дефайнами, выбирающими реализацию в зависимости от процессора, то в ассемблере нет ничего плохого.

Comment: Откуда Вы взяли, что вообще невозможно встроенное ассемблирование в х64? В gcc, в Intel C++ Compiler уже давно есть и прекрасно работает.

В той программе это было одно из узких мест, поскольку нужно было считывать данные из файлов (несколько сотен гигабайт), сделанных на Спарке, и записывать в разные файлы для обработки на PC. Позволило примерно на 10% ускорить программу.

Comment: >Откуда Вы взяли, что вообще невозможно встроенное ассемблирование в х64? В gcc, в Intel C++ Compiler уже давно есть и прекрасно работает.

 Не знаю. Просто так часто пишут. Наверное, они подразумевают только Visual C++, а я понял как вообще все компиляторы.

 Я думал, что в обработке файлов их слабое место - считывание с жёсткого диска, а сама обработка занимает мало времени.

Comment: Я же написал: одно из узких мест. И была получена реальная выгода.

Answer (score 0):

Преимущество asm-вставок для меня в том что я понимаю как это работает, а то знаете в чужом компиляторе и чёрт ногу сломит.

Comment: Тогда логично вообще все писать на ассемблере.

Comment: Старая хохма. Что значит "я понимаю, как оно работает"? На современных процессорах персоналок Вы не можете быть уверены в том, что Вы знаете, в какой последовательности эти команды выполняются. Мало ли чего Вы понаписали -- процессор лучше знает, что ему делать :)

Comment: Странная у тебя позиция. Зачем понимать, "как это работает", когда программист должен сосредотачиваться на более высокоуровневых понятиях? Пользователю твоей программы всё-равно, какие регистры и инструкции ты используешь. Что тебя не устраивает в работе компилятора?

Comment: Правильно. С весьма высокой вероятностью можно сказать, что работает так, как написано. А если неясно, что сам написал, то это уже не ассемблером исправлять.

Answer (score 0):

Преимущество asm-вставок для меня в том, что я понимаю, как это работает, а то знаете, в чужом компиляторе и чёрт ногу сломит.

Оформляю так:
беру из VS2005 файлы: `ml.exe,link.exe,lib.exe mspdb80.dll`
также `cmd.exe`.

Далее пишу в блокноте текст на ассемблере, например:

```
;***************************** asm_CheckNechet.asm ************************************
; Данный модуль возвращает 1 если число нечётное, в противном случае 0.
;**************************************************************************************
; Command Line (release):
;  ml -c "-Fl$(IntDir)\$(InputName).lst" "-Fo$(IntDir)\$(InputName).obj" "$(InputPath)"
; Outputs:
;  $(IntDir)\$(InputName).obj
.686
.model  flat,   c
.data
.code
asm_CheckNechet PROC
    pushad
    mov     EBP,    ESP 
;**************************************************************************************
    mov     ESI, DWORD PTR [EBP+36] ;загрузить указатель на входное число  //int
    mov     EDI, DWORD PTR [EBP+40] ;загрузить указатель на выходное число //float  
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    finit
    mov     EAX,  DWORD PTR [ESI]
    sar     EAX,  1 ;сдвигаем вправо
    jc          obxod1
    fld1
    fstp        DWORD PTR [EDI] ;число чётное
    popad
    ret
obxod1:
    fldz
    fstp        DWORD PTR [EDI] ;число нечётное
    popad
    ret 
asm_CheckNechet endp
 end
```

Далее с помощью заранее заготовленного батника компилю в объектник:

```
ml -c asm_CheckNechet.asm asm_CheckNechet.obj
```

Затем добавляю в библиотеку:

```
lib /OUT:my.lib asm_CheckNechet.obj
```

Ну, а дальше подключаю эту библиотеку к студии просто положив ее в соответствующую директорию.

В студии такая функция объявляется так:

```
extern "C" void asm_CheckNechet(const int*, float*);
```

Comment: Нужно или заключать в обратные кавычики, или перед каждой строкой отступать 4 пробела. В ответах есть волшебная кнопка 010101

Comment: Это не вставки ассемблера, а сам ассемблер. Вопрос был про вставки.

>Затем добавляю в библиотеку

 По-моему, можно просто obj файл без библиотеки подключать.

 Тебя что, два? dУГ и diГ?

Comment: не вижу большого смысла писать батники и прочая. Достаточно в студии настроить обработку асм файлов.... 3 секунды гугла и вуаля - http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/development/111275/ статейка готовая... (это если говорить об отдельных модулях на асме) - и дебагер будет работать...